# Copying Worksheets from a closed Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm trying to automate the copying of 3 Excel worksheets from a master file into any other Excel file via VBA code, but I keep getting an "*Error 1004: Copy Method Of Worksheet Class Failed*".

Here's my code:

```
Sub CopyandInsert()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set closedBook = Workbooks.Open("\\filepath\master_file.xlsx")
    closedBook.Sheets("Long Sheet Name One").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    closedBook.Sheets("Long Sheet Name Two").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    closedBook.Sheets("Long Sheet Name Three").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)
    closedBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

VBA is able to find and open the master file, but keeps breaking at the first copy line.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct sheet name?

Comment: Yeah...good question, thank you. Double checked and the sheet names are correct. :-(

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Sheets Using an Array of Sheet Names

**Cons**

- All sheets have to exist.
- At least one sheet has to be visible. Any hidden sheets will stay hidden.
- Any very hidden sheets will not be copied.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyandInsert()
    
    Const dFilePath As String = "C:\Test.xlsx"
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
    
    dwb.Sheets(SheetNames).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    'Thisworkbook.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

### Copy Sheets Using a Loop

```vb
Sub CopyandInsert2()
    
    Const dFilePath As String = "C:\Test.xlsx"
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
    
    Dim dsh As Object
    
    For Each dsh In dwb.Sheets(SheetNames)
        On Error GoTo ClearWorksheetError
        dsh.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next dsh
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    'Thisworkbook.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
    
ClearWorksheetError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description, _
        vbCritical
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

### PERSONAL.xlsb

- To make it work correctly, you need to select (look at) the file where you want to add the copied sheets, then open the macro-dialog and select the `CopyandInsert` macro.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyandInsert()
    
    Const dFilePath As String = "C:\Test.xlsx"
    Dim SheetNames As Variant
    SheetNames = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dFilePath)
    
    dwb.Sheets(SheetNames).Copy After:=swb.Sheets(1)
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'swb.Sheets(1).Select
    'swb.Save
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your code... but unfortunately it didn't work. VBA got hung up on "dwb.Sheets(SheetNames).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)"

Comment: It works on my end. Have you changed the names in the array? Is at least one of them visible? Are they maybe protected?

Comment: From your code, I updated the file path (the master file is on a share drive), and updated your sheet names to the actual names on the master file. None of them are hidden, if that's what you mean by "visible". And they're not protected, as far as I can tell. Thanks for the help though... much appreciated.

Comment: I've added another version. Would appreciate some feedback (how it behaves). It will show a message box on each error occurring when trying to copy the files.

Comment: Ok... so I was running all of your code in a Module within a PERSONAL.XLSB. I'm newish to all this so I'm 1/2 guessing with certain procedures. BUT... if I insert a new module within the target file, copy/paste your code, it all works perfectly. What's the deal? How do I make this code accessible anytime I open a random Excel file?

Comment: According to your code, `ThisWorkbook` is the target file, so if the code is in `PERSONAL.XLSB`, then the sheets will be copied to it. If there is a third file that I obviously don't know of, please do share some info.

Comment: yeah... .xlsb is a type of Excel file, apparently for saving macros. I'm just trying to have this VBA code available to any normal Excel file. Thanks again for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: But that doesn't mean that you can't use it for another file: just replace the occurrences of `Thisworkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook`. Of course, you need to always select (look at) the workbook where you are going to use this code before running it. Ooops, and I need to make a few changes. Give me 10 minutes.

Comment: I've added a third version. In the future, always mention that you're working from a `PERSONAL.xlsb` file because the code then is often slightly different.

Comment: That was it. Version 3 worked perfectly. Can't thank you enough... sorry for the back & forth.